# Understanding the Single Responsibility Principle

Tags: java, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

I am quite confused on how to determine if a single method has one responsibility being done just like the following code from the book Clean Code

```
public Money calculatePay(Employee e) throws InvalidEmployeeType {
        switch (e.type) {
            case COMMISSIONED:
                return calculateCommissionedPay(e);
            case HOURLY:
                return calculateHourlyPay(e);
            case SALARIED:
                return calculateSalariedPay(e);
            default:
                throw new InvalidEmployeeType(e.type);
        }
    }
```

As the author stated on this code snippet: "...**clearly does more than one thing.
Third, it violates the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) because there is more than one
reason for it to change.**". On a first glance at the code I was thinking that how come that the method violates SRP since if there is a change in the code it would be the switch statement only if there will be an added employee type but as I try to understand the method further I came up with a hypothesis on why it violates the said principle.

My hypothesis is that since the name of the method is `calculatePay(Employee e)` then the only responsibility of this method is for the payment computation as the method's name suggest but since inside the method there is a switch on filtering the type of Employee this filtering is now a different or another responsibility thus violates SRP. I don't know if I got it right.

Answer (score 12):

> "...clearly does more than one thing. Third, it violates the Single
>   Responsibility Principle (SRP) because there is more than one reason
>   for it to change."

There lies your answer. Every time a new `Employee.Type` is added that method will have to change. Also, the calculation for each `Employee.Type` might change too.

A better solution would be to create an [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) for Employee and each derivative of Employee having it's own implementation of `CalculatePay`. This way, only ONE class needs to changed when the Calculation changes or when a new `Employee.Type` is added.

Here is another extract from Clean Code that explains in more detail -

> The solution to this problem (see Listing 3-5) is to bury the switch
>   statement in the basement of an ABSTRACT FACTORY,9 and never let
>   anyone see it. The factory will use the switch statement to create
>   appropriate instances of the derivatives of Employee, and the various
>   functions, such as calculatePay, isPayday, and deliverPay, will be
>   dispatched polymorphically through the Employee interface. My general
>   rule for switch statements is that they can be tolerated if they
>   appear only once, are used to create polymorphic objects

Comment: thank you for the input, I would like to as on the `Also, the calculation for each Employee.Type might change too`. How does the calculation for the employee would affect the method? Since each type is just calling a method to perform the calculation, I think, and also based on your answer and on the statement given by the book can I assume that my hypothesis on how I understand the principle is correct?

Comment: The [Single Responsibility Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) should be seen in the context of a Class and not necessarily on Method level. This is why I'm saying that if any calculation changes you would need to update this class. If you moved this Method to a derivative of Employee, then only that class will have to change if the calculation needs to change.

Comment: @anathema also, if e.g. we want to calculate hourly payment differently (let's say working on weekend has an effect on the salary) then we might change calculateHourlyPay function signature (adding a boolean flag or a datetime), hence the calculatePay function is also need to be changed.

Answer (score 6):

I generally apply the SRP at the class level. It prevents classes becoming too big and taking on too many roles.

I treat the 'responsibilities' as conceptual. Therefore, I would argue that your method has only one responsibility: to calculate pay.

I try and follow Google's [guidelines](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) on this and look for these warning signs that suggest you're wandering away from the SRP:

- Summarising what the class does includes the word ‘and’.
- Class would be challenging for new team members or inexperienced developers
  to read and quickly ‘get it’.
- Class has fields that are only used in some methods.
- Class has static methods that only operate on parameters.

On another note, however, your code contains a switch statement that suggests you might be wandering away from the OCP...