# Can't understand why the code violates Single Responsibility Principle (in book 'clean code' by Robert C. Martin)

Tags: java

I'm reading the book 'Clean Code' by Robert C. Martin. The book said code under this paragraph violates Single Responsibility Principle But I don't know why!

```
Payroll.java

  Public Money calculatePay(Employee e)
  throws InvalidEmployeeType {
    switch (e.type) {
      case COMISSIONED:
        return calculateCommissionedPay(e);
      case HOURLY:
        return calculateHourlyPay(e);
      case SALARIED:
        return calculateSalariedPay(e);
      default:
        throw new InvalidEmployeeType(e.type);
    }
  }
```

I think 'calculate pay' only has responsibility for CFO. So, I thought this code doesn't violate SRP. However, the book said it's not. Could you help me, please?

Comment: what else does the book say? normally, it'll explain it.

Comment: It just says 'there are many reasons to change the code.' not specifically explained 
anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the Single Responsibility Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276095/understanding-the-single-responsibility-principle)

Comment: What page is this code listing from?

Comment: I'm reading translated book so, I can't say exactly but the number of code is 3-4. Thanks a lot!